# Error upload an extension to chrome web store

Tags: chrome-web-store

I am trying to upload an extension to chrome web store and get an error: Error publishing item.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orAHU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to log-out your email in your developer dashboard and log-in again. Make sure that you only log-in with the single account.